# ImportError: No module named error

Tags: python, python-2.7, numerical-methods, bisection

In Numerical Methods in Engineering with Python, 2nd Edition, Author: Jaan Kiusalaas, I wrote the same module found on page 146 that calculates the roots, f(x) = 0, using the bisection method:

```
from math import log,ceil
import error

def bisection2(f,x1,x2,switch=0,tol=1.0e-9):
        f1 = f(x1)
        if f1 == 0.0: return x1
        f2 = f(x2)
        if f2 == 0.0: return x2
        if f1*f2 > 0.0: error.err('Root is not bracketed')
        n = ceil(log(abs(x2 - x1)/epsilon)/log(2.0))
        for i in range(n):
            x3 = 0.5*(x1 + x2); f3 = f(x3)
            if (switch == 1) and (abs(f3) > abs(f1)) \
                                         (abs(f3) > abs(f2)):
                return None
            if f3 == 0.0:return x3
            if f2*f3 < 0.0:
                x1 = x3; f1 = f3
            else:
                x2 = x3; f2 = f3
        return (x1 + x2)/2.0
```

I am encountering the following error:

> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
>   /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, *where)
>       173             else:
>       174                 filename = fname
>   --> 175             **builtin**.execfile(filename, *where)
>
> /home/uwhpsc/Desktop/bisection2/bisection2.py in ()
>         1 from math import log,ceil
>   ----> 2 import error
>         3 
>         4 def bisection2(f,x1,x2,switch=0,tol=1.0e-9):
>         5         f1 = f(x1)
>
> ImportError: No module named error

Kindly could anyone please advise me how to solve this issue?

Comment: There is another bit of code somewhere that's intended to go in another file, probably called error.py that you need to "write"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this code work, you can remove the line that says:

```
import error
```

And on the line that says:

```
if f1*f2 > 0.0: error.err('Root is not bracketed')
```

Change that to:

```
if f1*f2 > 0.0: quit('Root is not bracketed')
```